Several variations of Ahmed integrals: $\int_0^1\frac1{(1+y^2)\sqrt{2+y^2}}\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{2-y^2}{4}}\right )\text{d}y=\frac{11\pi^2}{288}.$
The following are four integrals resembling Ahmed integrals:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&I_1=\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+y^2 \right )\sqrt{2+y^2}  } 
\arcsin\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2-y^2}{4} }  \right ) 
\text{d}y  = \frac{11\pi^2}{288},\\
&I_2=\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+y^2 \right )\sqrt{2+y^2}  } 
\arcsin\left ( \sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{3} }  \right ) 
\text{d}y  = \frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{\pi}{2} \arcsin\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \right ),\\
&I_3=\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+y^2 \right )\sqrt{2+y^2}  } 
\arctan\left ( \frac{\sqrt{(1-y^2 )\left ( 2+y^2 \right ) }}  {2}\right ) 
\text{d}y
=\pi\arctan\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }  \right ) -\frac{\pi^2}{6},\\
&I_4=\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+y^2 \right )\sqrt{2+y^2}  } 
\arctan\left ( {\sqrt{\frac{4-y^4}5}}\right ) 
\text{d}y
=\frac\pi2\arctan\left ( \sqrt{\frac35}   \right ) -\frac{\pi^2}{15}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
I derived them by some complex tricks, while two alternative approaches sprung up into my mind. We can handle them either by $S(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ or @Zacky's approach. For instance, using the latter we obtain an equivalent of $I_2$:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\left ( x^4-2x^2+1 \right ) }{x(1+x^2)(1+2x^2)(1+3x^2)}
\ln\left ( \left | \frac{1-x}{1+x}  \right |  \right ) \text{d}x
=\pi\arcsin\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3} }  \right ) -\frac{\pi^2}{12} 
\sim1.1111194977.
$$
This monster is actually solvable for the friendly interval, and we may employ residues to have a rapid verfication. Moreover, by borrowing some ideas from this previously posted question, we have
$$
\small\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )\left ( 1+y^2 \right ) 
\sqrt{3+x^2+y^2}  }\arcsin\left ( \sqrt{\frac{3+x^2+y^2}{5} }  \right ) 
\text{d}x\text{d}y
=2\pi\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right ) 
\sqrt{2+x^2} }\arcsin\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2+x^2}{5} }  \right )
\text{d}x
-\frac{\pi^2}{2}\arcsin\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{5} }  \right ) 
+\frac{\pi^3}{160},
$$
$$
\small\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right )\left ( 1+y^2 \right ) 
\sqrt{3+x^2+y^2}  }\arcsin\left ( \sqrt{\frac{3+x^2+y^2}{6} }  \right ) 
\text{d}x\text{d}y
=\pi\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\left ( 1+x^2 \right ) 
\sqrt{2+x^2} }\arcsin\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2+x^2}{6} }  \right )
\text{d}x
-\frac{\pi^2}{5}\arcsin\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{6} }  \right ) 
+\frac{\pi^3}{960}.
$$

Questions.

Do we have any alternative proofs and new results of such integrals? Especially with factors
$\frac{1}{(1+y^2)\sqrt{2+y^2}}$.
On whether it is possible to cope with the multiple integration?


Possibly related: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\sqrt{2+x^{2}}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{2+x^{2}}{4+x^{2}}}\right)dx=\frac{5\pi^{2}}{96}$$ which one can prove by using multiple integration and properties related to the Error function $\operatorname{erf}$.

Ahmed integral: $\int_0^1 \frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2+x^2}}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{2+x^2}}\ dx= \frac{5\pi^2}{96}$.
\begin{aligned}
I_1=&\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+y^2 \right )\sqrt{2+y^2}  } 
\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{2-y^2}{4} } 
\ \text{d}y \\
\overset{ibp}=&\ \frac{\pi^2}{36}+\int_0^1 \frac{y\tan^{-1}\frac y{\sqrt{2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{4-y^4}}dy\\
 =&\ \frac{\pi^2}{36}+\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{2-y^2}(2+y^2+y^2x^2)}dx\ dy\\
=&\ \frac{\pi^2}{36}+\int_0^1 \frac{\frac\pi4}{1+x^2}-\frac{\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2+x^2}}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{2+x^2}}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac{\pi^2}{36}+ \frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{5\pi^2}{96}=  \frac{11\pi^2}{288}\\
\\
 I_2=&\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{\left ( 1+y^2 \right )\sqrt{2+y^2}  } 
\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{3} } 
\ \text{d}y \\
\overset{ibp}=&\int_0^1 \frac{y\tan^{-1}\frac y{\sqrt{2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(2+y^2)}}dy\\
 =&\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{1-y^2}(2+y^2+y^2x^2)}dx\ dy\\
=&\ \frac\pi4 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{\sqrt2}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{3+x^2}}\ dx\\
=&\ \frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \\
\\
 I_3=& \int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{1}{( 1+y^2 )\sqrt{2+y^2}  } 
\tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{(1-y^2 )\left ( 2+y^2 \right ) }}  {2}
\text{d}y\\
 \overset{ibp}=&\int_0^1 \frac{2y(2y^2+1)\tan^{-1}\frac y{\sqrt{2+y^2}}}{(2-y^2)(3+y^2)\sqrt{(1-y^2)(2+y^2)}}dy\\
 =&\int_0^1 \left(\frac{2y}{2-y^2}- \frac{2y}{3+y^2}\right)\frac{\tan^{-1}\frac y{\sqrt{2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(2+y^2)}}dy\\
=&\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2-y^2}- \frac{1}{3+y^2}\right)\frac{2y^2}{(2+y^2+x^2y^2) \sqrt{1-y^2}}dx\ dy\\
 =&\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{2}{(2+x^2) \sqrt{1-y^2}}\left(\frac{1}{2-y^2}- \frac{1}{2+y^2+x^2y^2}\right)dy\ dx\\
 - &\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{2}{(1+3x^2) \sqrt{1-y^2}}\left(\frac{3}{3+y^2}- \frac{2}{2+y^2+x^2y^2}\right)dy\ dx\\
=& \ \frac\pi{\sqrt2}\int_0^1\bigg(1-\frac1{\sqrt{3+x^2}}\bigg)\frac1{2+x^2}dx \\
 & -\frac\pi{2}\int_0^1\bigg(\sqrt3-\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{3+x^2}}\bigg)\frac1{1+3x^2}dx \\
=& \ \frac\pi2 \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }-\frac\pi2 \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2} }-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+ \frac\pi2 \tan^{-1}{\sqrt{2} }\\
=&\ \pi\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } -\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
\end{aligned}

(+1) Very nice solutions involving straightforward steps.
